# UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh on iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I have an app which is to be run on both iPhone and iPad. I am setting a UIBarButton Item in one of my ViewControllers but for some reason it shows on the iPhone but not on the iPad (Simulator or real device).

I am using the following code to get the button image (which is a system button image) for both iPhone and iPad"

```
UIBarButtonItem *showButtonButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(loadButtonVC)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = showButtonButton;
```

I am at a loss. Both devices are running iOS 7 and the app is targeted at only iOS 7. But the image does not show on the iPad, the button is there as it still responds to pressing it.

Comment: Your code on a fresh universal project works like a charm on both iPhone/iPad. Are you sure that the controller on iPad is embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: Yeah it's definitely embedded in a NavigationController, it's the Root ViewController. I can set the button in the Storyboard and it works. Which will do for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self
                                   action:@selector(loadButtonVC)];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem. leftBarButtonItem = refreshBtn;
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. I can't see what is going wrong at all.

Comment: thats weird then,because i also had the same problem but worked with above code.have u tried the custom button??not the System refresh button..may be that could b the issue then

Comment: I have used a custom button but the image is slightly different. Seeing as i'm using the system I can't get it as perfect and can't seem to find a link to get the asset directly.